# How can I test my iOS application, using Xcode, in another language without changing my language preferences on my iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, localization

I have an application that I would like to test in another language. Using Xcode is there a way to test the application in another language without changing my language preferences on my iPhone?

Comment: Why don't you want to change the device's language? It's how real users will be using it. It's the only valid way to test.

Comment: @rmaddy Because of the time it takes to switch languages in the iPhone, you have to wait for the OS to change everything. And so if you are going back and forth a lot between languages this is time consuming. I would think there would have to be a way to select a language folder before running the application, which would make it much more developer friendly.

Comment: This is what test devices are for. Just keep the test device in the language you are testing.

Comment: @rmaddy What if you are a small company or an individual and are testing 5 languages? No person or small company are going to want to pay for 5 devices just to test languages on. But I can see how that would work great if you had a new iPhone and an old one laying around. They shouldn't expect that of a developer though, after all I am already paying to be a developer.

Comment: @rmaddy Question about your edit... do I need to mention xCode for it to be a relevant tag?

Comment: I removed the xcode tag because it has nothing to do with your question at all. Read the tag's description.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68828/discussion-between-cedric-and-rmaddy).

Comment: Try a dozen languages times at least six different screen sizes times two or three different OS versions.  It isn't practical to create that many *simulator* configurations, much less have that many devices.  In fact, it exceeds the maximum number of devices that even two USB buses can support unless you know how to design custom hub silicon.

Comment: @dgatwood Actually I was maybe hoping for a support library or something that would simulate using the OS localization. So instead of asking the OS what localization I have set it would just read from a library that I would add to my application files. The possibilities are endless and I was just checking if there were any viable possibilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is very simple. In Xcode go to menu "Product" and Alt + click on "Run..." menu item.

This will open schemes. On "Run" scheme open "Options" tab. Select "Application Language" and Run.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, not really I guess. The only other way is to implement the whole language choosing possibility by yourself, i.e. give the user (or just yourself as developer) the possibility to change the language manually. But that's really a lot of overhead and you'll probably not want that.

There is no quick other way of doing so I'm afraid :/

Answer (score 0):

You can create instances of the simulator with Xcode 6.1 (windows->devices) , see attached ss.

[image: devices menu]

So, create a iphone-language version. This new 'simulator' is now available in the drop down list of devices when you build and run. Run in that new target device. When your app start, you should see the proper simulator in the window banner as here :

[image]

Now go into settings and set the language to your desired target. Should work, but have not tested with an actual multi-language app myself.

Comment: This didn't work. It might be a bug, but on the simulator once I changed the language preferences still used the English storyboard version. But when I ran the same project unchanged on the iPhone it worked correctly.

Comment: After having set the language pref, try deleting the app and running again (just a guess).

Comment: I tried that a couple of times and it still didn't work.

Comment: @mcphersonjr were you able to find a workaround or fix? I believe I'm facing the same issue as well.

Comment: @user805981 I have not found any additional workarounds or fixes. I basically just had to power through. Sorry.

Comment: @mcphersonjr so basically you had to use different simulators with different languages settings right?

Comment: @user805981 I am remembering correctly (after 2 years), I had to run on the iPhone because the simulator would not use the correct language based data in app.